# Update many records by id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working with mongoose on a project and I have the following issue:
I need to update many records by their ids (these ids were stored in an array). I've tried this method:

```
 Collection.update({$in:{"_id":ids}}, {$set:{data_of_id}}, {upsert : true},
                 {"multi": true}, function(err, res){
                                        
                if(err){ console.log(err) };
                console.log(res);               
 });
```

ids[] is the ids of the collection I need to update, and data_of_id is the new records which will replace the old records. But I don't know how to associate these ids with each record in the array. I tried to put the update query into a foreach method too, but no success. The query above doesn't return any error or message, the called method was executed but don't execute the query.

Comment: Can you share more details? Like what error you're getting? Ideally $in helps to update multiple documents.

Comment: The `$in` is fine, but you can't apply a different update to each doc. You'll need to use [`bulkWrite`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) for this.

Answer (score 3):

The [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) syntax is incorrect, it should be:

```
{ field: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } }
```

So, you should write it like this:

```
Collection.update({_id: {$in: ids}}, ...);
```

Comment: But, i'm using array ids just to find the records wich will be updated. May i'm using $in for the wrong purpose i think.

Answer (score -2):

I've solved doing by this way:

```
        datas.forEach(function(data){

            Collection.update({"_id":data._id},
                data, {upsert : true},{new : true}, function(err, res){
                if(err) console.log(err);
            });

        });
```